# Tab Key Not Working to Select Controls

Tags: macos, shortcut, accessibility

I have **Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** selected in System Preferences, so but the tab key isn't working to select different controls (such as drop-down menus and checkboxes) in application dialog boxes. For example, I tried the **Preview** Preferences dialog box.

I have tried multiple different applications, and I do not to my knowledge have any additional software running that would be intercepting the tab key press.

Is this a problem that is local to my computer, or am I missing something important?

MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.2

[image]

Comment: Does anyone else running Catalina have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've discovered seems to be using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle dialog navigation on/off. It might reset after restarting the computer, but it seems to enable navigation in all applications.

Comment: This is yet another example of a completely baffling macOS "feature" that is frustratingly obscure. Thanks for the suggestion.